# Use select statement results in while loop

Tags: sql-server, while-loop

I have this query:

```
SELECT name FROM SomeDB.sys.objects WHERE type IN ('P') AND name LIKE('dbo%');
```

What I want to do now is use the name I selected from the table in a while loop.
Like this (pseudo code)

```
WHILE (select < select.END)
BEGIN  
   DROP PROC select.name 
END
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Do you want to drop all procedures? or something?

Comment: Yes Im using a service broker and when the app doesn't shutdown normally. And it restarts I want to start with a clean DB with no broker items any more. Actually it is all about the reuse of the select in the while I can't figure out.

Answer (score 1):

For dropping database objects you can use dynamic script like below. If any dependencies are exist then you need to drop parent first.

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @SQL=(
SELECT 'DROP PROCEDURE '+NAME+';' FROM SYS.OBJECTS WHERE TYPE IN ('P') 
FOR XML PATH('') )
--select @sql
EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL
```

Comment: what does the `FOR XML PATH('')`?

Comment: @WagoL We will use For Xml path('') just for concatenation of all rows into a single one.

Comment: I get this error `Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '-'.` This the query I executed. `DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @SQL=(
SELECT 'DROP PROCEDURE '+name+';' FROM SMARTnet.SYS.OBJECTS WHERE TYPE IN ('P') AND name LIKE('dbo%')
FOR XML PATH('') )
--select @sql
EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL`